# Where can I find the explanation of each field of the result returned by the api of blockchain.info?

Tags: blockchain.info

Such as in this result: https://blockchain.info/rawtx/6b1c57d98a557b5f578c02f6c386ef049df5890ebddd01d286bf345f47c5cecc

I don't know what ex. the fields "tx_index", "type", "n" mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation for that call, such as it is, [here](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api). It's not very helpful.

I can give you a few tips, though.

- `n` is the vout of the input. A vout plus a txid unambiguously specify a transaction output, and are collectively known as an outpoint. [More](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/outpoint).
- `tx_index` is a field used by blockchain.info, and has no meaning outside of blockchain.info's api.
- No idea what `type` means. Looking at a few transactions at random, it always seems to be zero.